# Unexpected result of `predict_function` (Empty batch_outputs) Please use `Model.compile

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I need to install TensorFlow 2.2.0

why? because this repo (https://github.com/GantMan/nsfw_model) is requesting it and now matter what I tried can't make it work with newer TensorFlows

How can I install TensorFlow 2.2.0  on Windows 10 and Python 3.10?

The error I am getting is and I am not able to fix it

```
(venv) G:\nsfw_model>python a.py
2023-08-14 00:33:39.437427: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-08-14 00:33:40.148302: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1525] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 21643 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6
2023-08-14 00:33:40.149891: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1525] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 9603 MB memory:  -> device: 1, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060, pci bus id: 0000:05:00.0, compute capability: 8.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\nsfw_model\a.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(predict.classify(model, 'test'))
  File "G:\nsfw_model\nsfw_detector\predict.py", line 67, in classify
    probs = classify_nd(model, images, predict_args)
  File "G:\nsfw_model\nsfw_detector\predict.py", line 77, in classify_nd
    model_preds = model.predict(nd_images, **predict_args)
  File "G:\nsfw_model\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "G:\nsfw_model\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1997, in predict
    raise ValueError('Unexpected result of `predict_function` '
ValueError: Unexpected result of `predict_function` (Empty batch_outputs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for more information of where went wrong, or file a issue/bug to `tf.keras`.
```

predict.py

```
#! python

import argparse
import json
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join, exists, isdir, abspath

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow_hub as hub


IMAGE_DIM = 299   # required/default image dimensionality

def load_images(image_paths, image_size, verbose=True):
    '''
    Function for loading images into numpy arrays for passing to model.predict
    inputs:
        image_paths: list of image paths to load
        image_size: size into which images should be resized
        verbose: show all of the image path and sizes loaded
    
    outputs:
        loaded_images: loaded images on which keras model can run predictions
        loaded_image_indexes: paths of images which the function is able to process
    
    '''
    loaded_images = []
    loaded_image_paths = []

    if isdir(image_paths):
        parent = abspath(image_paths)
        image_paths = [join(parent, f) for f in listdir(image_paths) if isfile(join(parent, f))]
    elif isfile(image_paths):
        image_paths = [image_paths]

    for img_path in image_paths:
        try:
            if verbose:
                print(img_path, "size:", image_size)
            image = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(img_path, target_size=image_size)
            image = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(image)
            image /= 255
            loaded_images.append(image)
            loaded_image_paths.append(img_path)
        except Exception as ex:
            print("Image Load Failure: ", img_path, ex)
    
    return np.asarray(loaded_images), loaded_image_paths

def load_model(model_path):
    if model_path is None or not exists(model_path):
        raise ValueError("saved_model_path must be the valid directory of a saved model to load.")
    
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path, custom_objects={'KerasLayer': hub.KerasLayer},compile=False)
    return model


def classify(model, input_paths, image_dim=IMAGE_DIM, predict_args={}):
    """
    Classify given a model, input paths (could be single string), and image dimensionality.
    
    Optionally, pass predict_args that will be passed to tf.keras.Model.predict().
    """
    images, image_paths = load_images(input_paths, (image_dim, image_dim))
    probs = classify_nd(model, images, predict_args)
    return dict(zip(image_paths, probs))


def classify_nd(model, nd_images, predict_args={}):
    """
    Classify given a model, image array (numpy)
    
    Optionally, pass predict_args that will be passed to tf.keras.Model.predict().
    """
    model_preds = model.predict(nd_images, **predict_args)
    # preds = np.argsort(model_preds, axis = 1).tolist()
    
    categories = ['drawings', 'hentai', 'neutral', 'porn', 'sexy']

    probs = []
    for i, single_preds in enumerate(model_preds):
        single_probs = {}
        for j, pred in enumerate(single_preds):
            single_probs[categories[j]] = float(pred)
        probs.append(single_probs)
    return probs


def main(args=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="""A script to perform NFSW classification of images""",
        epilog="""
        Launch with default model and a test image
            python nsfw_detector/predict.py --saved_model_path mobilenet_v2_140_224 --image_source test.jpg
    """, formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
    
    submain = parser.add_argument_group('main execution and evaluation functionality')
    submain.add_argument('--image_source', dest='image_source', type=str, required=True, 
                            help='A directory of images or a single image to classify')
    submain.add_argument('--saved_model_path', dest='saved_model_path', type=str, required=True, 
                            help='The model to load')
    submain.add_argument('--image_dim', dest='image_dim', type=int, default=IMAGE_DIM,
                            help="The square dimension of the model's input shape")
    if args is not None:
        config = vars(parser.parse_args(args))
    else:
        config = vars(parser.parse_args())

    if config['image_source'] is None or not exists(config['image_source']):
        raise ValueError("image_source must be a valid directory with images or a single image to classify.")
    
    model = load_model(config['saved_model_path'])    
    image_preds = classify(model, config['image_source'], config['image_dim'])
    print(json.dumps(image_preds, indent=2), '\n')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```